# Calculate width of Views so that they always fit on screen

Tags: java, android, dynamic, view, width

I need to dynamically calculate the width of the bars in the diagram that I am drawing.

The minimum width has to be 4 pixels and the maximum 50 pixels.

How do I calculate the width so that even when I need more bars they dynamically set the width and fit on the screen?

Right now it is all HardCoded to be either 4 or 50 pixels so if you could suggest something I would be thankful.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

```
    public void drawBars(int numberOfRates) {
    this.removeAllViews();
    final ViewGroup nullParent = null;
    this.addView(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_bar_diagram, nullParent));
    LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);

    int width, height, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin, textBottomMargin;

    verticalMargin = calculateDpi(16);

    if (((numberOfRates * calculateDpi(50)) + (numberOfRates * calculateDpi(5))) < displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
        width = calculateDpi(50);
        horizontalMargin = calculateDpi(5);
    } else {
        width = 0;
        horizontalMargin = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRates; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            textBottomMargin = 0;
            height = calculateDpi(50);
        } else if (i == (numberOfRates - 1)) {
            textBottomMargin = calculateDpi(16);
            height = calculateDpi(150);
        } else {
            textBottomMargin = calculateDpi(16);
            height = calculateDpi(100);
        }

        TextBarView textBarView = new TextBarView(getContext());

        textBarView.drawBar(i + 1,
                width,
                height,
                horizontalMargin,
                verticalMargin,
                textBottomMargin);

        parentView.addView(textBarView);
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: How are you inflating your widgets now?

Comment: @VladislavSazanovich I draw the CustomBarViews by calling parent.addView(BarView) and I pass a width to LayoutParams but that is HardCoded right now. I need to somehow calculate the width of the bars depending on how many bars I want to draw.

Comment: @VladislavSazanovich I just added the code I use for drawing as an EDIT to the question, if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many `Views` it is not a very good idea to add them into `ViewGroup`. I would recommend you to draw your widgets on the `Canvas`.

```
public class CustomDiagram extends View {

    private int numberOfItems;

    public CustomDiagram(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomDiagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomDiagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth(); 
        // Here you have full width of your view
        // You also have numberOfItems here

    }
}
```

Comment: @drilonreqica. Do you need more code in `onDraw()`?

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be usefull

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = btn.getLayoutParams();
    int width =layoutParams.width;
    int hight=layoutParams.height;
```

Comment: this is not really helpful in this respective case!